# White screen in plugin "ChatBot"

Tags: buildfire

I have created the ChatBot plugin and it doesn't work(just white screen, without errors). I was using debugger, but console is empty, no errors. Plugin works in app.buildfire.com and in SDK, but in BuildFire Previewer and Play Store/App Store app doesn't work. Why?

**UPDATE:**
I'm not using buildfire FireBase integration. I'm using BuildFire api and FireBase RealTime Datastore in my plugin. Must I use buildfire FireBase integration? I need to use only Firebase RealTime Database (not Firestore).

Comment: Using BuildFire's Firebase integration or not shouldn't make any difference. Things you may want to check is http vs https (all mobile integrations must be https) also try using the remote debugger. http://debug.buildfire.com + ship logs from the device

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TqxKa0O It's screenshots of debugger. What does it mean?

Comment: The first image shows you all the framed components of the app. You want to select the launcher or widget. It depends on where your plugin is loaded. It doesn't seem like you're getting console errors. so what I would do is start adding into your plugin console logs, warnings, and errors at each step of the process. you can then monitor the logs to see where it stops. also good to see the network traffic if it ever hits your bot server.